# What's wrong with having main class not as a superclass?

Tags: java

Here, I have a superclass called 'Staff'. My main method is in a separate class called 'Program_2A'. The filename given is Program_2A.java. Eclipse is showing an error in the second line of the program saying

> Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files)

I don't understand what's wrong by having the main class, not as a superclass.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Staff {
    private int Staff_ID;
    private String Name;
    private int Phone;
    private int Salary;

    public Staff(int staff_id, String name, int phone, int salary)
    {
        Staff_ID = staff_id;
        Name = name;
        Phone = phone;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("\t" + Staff_ID + "\t" + Name + "\t" + Phone + "\t" + Salary);
    }
}
class Teaching extends Staff
{
    private String Domain;
    private int Publication;

    public Teaching(int staff_id, String name, int phone, int salary, String domain, int publication) {
        super(staff_id,name,phone,salary);
        Domain = domain;
        Publication = publication;
    }
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("\t" + Domain + "\t" + Publication);
    }
}
class Technical extends Staff
{
    private String Skills;
    public Technical(int staff_id, String name, int phone, int salary, String skills) {
        super(staff_id,name,phone,salary);
        Skills = skills;
    }
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("\t" + Skills);
    }
}
class Contract extends Staff
{
    private int Contract;
    public Contract(int staff_id, String name, int phone, int salary, int contract) {
        super(staff_id,name,phone,salary);
        Contract = contract;
}
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("\t" + Contract);
    }
}

class Program_2A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Staff St[] = new Staff[3];
        St[0] = new Teaching(1, "ABC", 1234, 10000, "CSE", 3);
        St[1] = new Technical(2, "DEF", 5678, 200000, "C++");
        St[2] = new Contract(3, "GHI", 9012, 50000, 3);

        System.out.println("STAFF ID \t NAME \t PHONE \t SALARY \t DOMAIN \t PUBLICATIONS \t SKILLS \t PERIOD");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            St[i].display();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the class with the `main` method be `public`?

Comment: @Gendarme It doesn't need to be public

Comment: The message you've quoted doesn't look/sound like an error, but more like an information during a refactoring step.

Comment: I tried!
Still the same error.

Comment: And it doesn't have anything to do with the title of your question.

Comment: I can reproduce, when trying to `mvn execute`: `--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ so53905874 ---
Error: Main method not found in class Staff, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: maybe true, the main class don't have to be public, but at least the (class) file name must match ... solution: `Staff.java` will only work, when you move "pstvm" to Staff class... or change visibility of Staff (class) to `private/package/protected` + rename `Staff.java` to `Program_2A.java`.

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are written in camelCase, class names in PascalCase. No underscores, except for constants, which are in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, one file can only contain one public class.

So please change `class Program_2A` to `public class Program_2A` and remove `public` keyword before `Staff` class.